# Hiding Actions via Automation Step

Tags: acumatica

I know you can disable some actions via Automation Step. But can you also explicitly hide them ? I understand a customisation can achieve the same result. Automation Step however is quick and easy to roll out.

TIA

Comment: The only way I know how to hide it is via code.  I vaguely recall seeing a note some time back saying that automation steps can disable but not hide an action.  This might be version specific, and there is a replacement of Automation Steps rolling out starting in 2020 R1.  What is your Acumatica version, and what screen?  (I understand that not all screens in 2020 R1 support the new automation yet.)

Comment: We're on MYOB Advance variant of Acumatica. So offically, we're still on 2019 R1 version. R2 is just being "evaluated". Screen I'm talking about ? Say the Contact screen for example. There's an action called "Convert to Business Account" and it should be a one-off. Once the Contact is converted. This action should not show anymore.

Comment: @Rick you can add a condition to hide the action in the RowSelected event handler

Comment: Thanks, Rick.  If you are on any version of 2019, that tells me it's the older style automation steps.  As you pointed out and Samvel reiterated, you may need to defer to using code to outright hide them with *MyAction.SetVisible(false);*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Rick the only why to "Hide" them is to remove all entries of the action from all automation steps from page/screen. If there are any entries even if they are not active the code will still load them in the menus(grayed out).

Option 1: Remove all "steps" that have the action in them for that page.

Option 2: Hide the action using code:

```
 protected void SOShipment_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
 { 
       ActionNameHere.SetVisible(true);
 }
```

Comment: Option 1 nailed it. Thanks !